# Social Sound Design RSS Feed

Tags: internet, ssd

Does anyone know if it's possible to integrate the question feed from SSD homepage into my Igoogle home page? I was just thinking of making SSD my home page but if the above can be done that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RSS question feed is here.](http://feeds.feedburner.com/SocialSoundDesign) Otherwise just use the SSD home address and paste this into your RSS reader.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Safarie, the RSS icon will appear in the search bar (where you type the web adresses), just click it :o ! haha I actually read your question from my google reader ;)